# error: no operator found which takes a right-hand QUdpSocket

Tags: c++, qt

Hello I use [**QT**](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qudpsocket.html) for developing I have this c++ code:

```
#include "udp.h"

udp::udp(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
   socket=new QUdpSocket(this);
   socket-> bind(QHostAddress::LocalHost,12345);
   connect(socket,SIGNAL(Readyread()),this ,SLOT(Readyread()));
}
```

This is example I just got from internet .
well i get an error says:

> error: C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand
>   operand of type 'QUdpSocket *' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Please guide me how can I solve this error.

Comment: What is the declaration of `socket`?

Comment: Looking into my crystal ball: socket is declared as `QUdpSocket ` instead of `QUdpSocket* `

Comment: @SergeyA well I used QUdpSocket*  and it   worked ,i think your comment was useful

Comment: @Muath, I need reputation :) Would you mind accepting my answer than?

Comment: @SergeyA i told you abt your comment to put it in a answer :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket` should be declared as `QUdpSocket*`, not `QUdpSocket`